# Ubuntu, lock screen but do not screensave

Tags: gnome, screensaver, ubuntu-18.04, gdm

When I do not use my graphical session anymore, the screensaver automatically lock it and power off the screen to save energy.

I want it to keep locking my session but not to power off the screen, is it possible ?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with default gnome display manager.

Thank you,

Matias

Comment: see what you can change in `System Settings` > `Brightness & Lock`

Comment: There is no more Brightness & Lock in ubuntu 18.04 but there is settings> power. I configured it to never blanck the screen but it does not change my problem. I had the same issue in ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described in this thread on [ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263610) it looks like this is part of the **gnome-screensaver-command** and there is no easy way to disable it. Try replacing the default screensaver with another one, like xscreensaver.

Hint: when you manually lock your screen, just hold the buttons a second longer and the screen won't turn off.

Comment: Holding it for a second longer actually worked like a charm, lmao

Comment: This works wonderfully. I wonder if this was intentional. Cause if it was that's a clever way to implement this functionality. If only there was some kind of a detailed documentation where you could find stuff like that.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me! This hint works kkk